# Retrieved data from XML using SQL-SERVER-2016 containing namespace

Tags: xml, sql-server-2016

Before this, received XML without namespace in AppHdr and Document and I able to retrieved data from it.

My query before newly XML introduced:

```
SELECT XMLData.Value('(/Root/AppHdr/BizMsgIdr)[1]', 'CHAR(16)') As MessageID,
       XMLData.Value('(/Root/Document/CorpActnGnlInf/OffclCorpActnEvtId)[1]', 'CHAR(16)') As EventID
FROM Announcement
```

Newly XML received as below:

```
<Root>
  <AppHdr xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <BizMsgIdr>MY190531X0000007</BizMsgIdr>
  </AppHdr>
  <Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:seev.031.001.08" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <CorpActnGnlInf>
      <OffclCorpActnEvtId>MY190531BONU0007</OffclCorpActnEvtId>
    </CorpActnGnlInf>
  </Document>
</Root>
```

Please assist on how new query with newly XML introduce.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the namespace in your query, or use `WITH NAMESPACE`. Here are a couple of links:

- https://sqlwithmanoj.com/tag/with-xmlnamespaces/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/add-namespaces-to-queries-with-with-xmlnamespaces?view=sql-server-2017